# AJAX & React: Console.log is not working?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Profile from './Github/Profile.jsx';

class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: 'TedSean',
            userData: [],
            userRepos: [],
            perPage: 5
        }
    }
    profileData() {
        $.ajax({

            url: 'https://api.github.com/users/'+this.state.username+'?client_id='+this.props.clientId+'&client_secret='+this.props.clientSecret,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err){
               alert(err); 
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        this.profileData();
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <div> 
                {this.props.username}
           </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use AJAX with Github API to  get profile data but don't know why it is not working. Can anybody explain why JSON Data is not getting logged in dev tools ?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: is ajax successful ?

Comment: Yes Ajax is successful.

Comment: how is componentDidMount invoked ?

Comment: @brk don't know if i m alerting the success function i m getting the object using JSON.stringify but not through console.log

Comment: client_secret shouldn't be used client side, [__"Every registered OAuth application is assigned a unique Client ID and Client Secret. The Client Secret should not be shared!"__](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/basics-of-authentication/#registering-your-app)

Comment: Its client-side implementation @PatrickEvans

Comment: Because i wanted to invoke profileData after render @brk

Comment: @PatrickEvans It doesn't matter to me now as i'm on development stage rather production.

Answer (score 0):

try this console log

```
console.log('data' + data);
```

Comment: That's make no sense, i fixed it by resetting the dev tools.